# Facebook iOS SDK - open session and request read permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using

```
(void)openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehavior)behavior completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler
```

to open my session, which works fine.  After open, I then get my read permissions with:

```
(void)requestNewReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions completionHandler:(FBSessionRequestPermissionResultHandler)handler
```

This works fine, but for users signing in through Mobile Safari (or likely the Facebook iOS app, haven't tested), users get jumped back and forth twice (tap login in my app, jump to Mobile Safari, log in there, jump back to my app, jump back to Mobile Safari, approve permissions, jump back to my app.

Returning users - those who have signed out of my app (and token removed), also get a double-jump - each time Mobile Safari tells the user they've already approved the app.

I'm using openWithBehavior because I prioritize the native iOS login using `FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent`.  I don't see a version of this combined with an initial permissions request (such as `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions...`).

I was hoping that, for subsequent logins, permissions would already be known via `session.permissions` but in testing that value is null until `requestNewReadPermissions` is called.

Is it possible to remove the double-jump from either or both scenarios (first user login, subsequent user login) yet still achieve the same permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "init" your session with read permissions by calling the initWithPermissions: method. Then call openWithBehavior:completionHandler: which will do only 1 open call with the permissions you've already set.

Comment: Perfect!  I missed that in the headers.  Thanks!